# Dealing With Pervasive 13's Ridgid StartUp Dependencies

Tags: windows-services, pervasive

How can I delay the start up of a windows service until internet accessibility is verified?

[Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/) has two registered windows services that start each time you reboot the server. If dns happens to not be available, at the time that these engines are started, then the databases remains inaccessible (indefinitely) from all other workstations on the network, until I reboot the windows server hosting Pervasive 13 (a 2nd time).

I suspect that each time you start Pervasive 13, it probably checks to see if your key is valid via the internet. If the internet is not available at engine-start-time, it doesn't seem to recover. Meaning, even if the internet becomes available (shortly) after start time, the database remains inaccessible from all workstations until you restart Pervasive (at a time that the internet is indeed available).

This makes it to where you can't restart your dns servers at the same time you restart the server hosting Pervasive 13. You have to restart the dns servers first, and wait until they're fully functioning, before restarting the server that's hosting Pervasive 13.

If Pervasive 13 is this internet dependent, and it cannot recover when you start it at a time that dns is unavailable, then I'm wanting to delay the start of these services until these dns-dependencies are verified to be available. There is no sense in even starting the engines if they're so rigidly dependent on internet accessibility at start time, with no ability to recover when the internet becomes available later than start time.

How can I delay the start up of these windows service until internet accessibility is verified?

Answer (score 1):

There was a suggestion at one time to set a dependency to WMI but I believe that was addressed in v11.  You could also delay the start by changing the Startup Type to "Automatic (Delayed Start)."  The last suggestion would be to upgrade to Zen v15 (the current version as of this post) might address this issue.

Comment: I've already tried the `Automatic (Delayed Start)` option. The delay must not be enough, because it has no effect. The code should be changed, so that it only prevents accessibility if the key has not been properly authenticated in x number of days; not just at the instance of start up. That's ridiculously rigid for a customer whose paid over $5,000.00 for a valid key and licenses. This means if we happen to reboot the server, during an internet outage, business ceases to operate. Not cool!